# To which p-value should I look at? Of the regression coefficient or of the Average Marginal Effect?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, logit, marginal-effect

I am trying to analyse this `logit` regression model using `R`. I wish to identify the effect of a treament variable (`dummy.tratamento`) onto the probability of reelection of a political candidate (`dummy.eleito`). My treatment variable is also interacted with a continuous variable that indicates the degree of political competition in a candidate's city election (`Concorrencia`).

`Escolaridade`, `Raca` and `DESCRICAO_SEXO` are all factors. `votos.cidade` is continuous.

```
library(margins)
modelo <- glm(dummy.eleito ~ dummy.tratamento + Escolaridade +
             Raca + DESCRICAO_SEXO + votos.cidade + dummy.prefeito +
             dummy.tratamento:Concorrencia + Concorrencia,
           data = base_cross.section, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

Both of the coefficients involving my treatment variable are really significant, although with different signs:

```
Call:
glm(formula = dummy.eleito ~ dummy.tratamento + Escolaridade + 
    Raca + DESCRICAO_SEXO + votos.cidade + dummy.prefeito + dummy.tratamento:Concorrencia + 
    Concorrencia, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = base_cross.section)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.5810  -1.2850   0.9042   1.0285   1.6080  

Coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                      5.245e-01  1.573e-01   3.335 0.000852 ***
dummy.tratamento                -1.999e-01  5.309e-02  -3.766 0.000166 ***
EscolaridadeMÉDIO_INCOMPLETO     8.912e-02  3.487e-02   2.556 0.010587 *  
EscolaridadeSUPERIOR_COMPLETO    2.965e-01  3.362e-02   8.820  < 2e-16 ***
EscolaridadeSUPERIOR_INCOMPLETO  2.075e-01  2.995e-02   6.930 4.22e-12 ***
RacaBRANCA                      -1.552e-01  1.522e-01  -1.020 0.307740    
RacaINDÍGENA                    -6.069e-01  2.658e-01  -2.283 0.022442 *  
RacaPreta_Parda                 -2.294e-01  1.524e-01  -1.506 0.132141    
DESCRICAO_SEXOMASCULINO          3.004e-01  3.177e-02   9.457  < 2e-16 ***
votos.cidade                     7.527e-07  9.462e-08   7.955 1.80e-15 ***
dummy.prefeito                   2.810e-01  2.718e-02  10.339  < 2e-16 ***
Concorrencia                    -5.908e-02  2.496e-03 -23.670  < 2e-16 ***
dummy.tratamento:Concorrencia    2.495e-02  4.217e-03   5.917 3.28e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 54123  on 39893  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 53232  on 39881  degrees of freedom
AIC: 53258

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

However, these are my average marginal effects:

```
summary(margins(modelo))



                      factor     AME     SE        z      p   lower   upper
                    Concorrencia -0.0129 0.0005 -24.8938 0.0000 -0.0139 -0.0119
         DESCRICAO_SEXOMASCULINO  0.0723 0.0077   9.3851 0.0000  0.0572  0.0875
                  dummy.prefeito  0.0667 0.0064  10.3914 0.0000  0.0541  0.0793
                dummy.tratamento  0.0053 0.0067   0.7854 0.4322 -0.0079  0.0185
    EscolaridadeMÉDIO_INCOMPLETO  0.0215 0.0084   2.5570 0.0106  0.0050  0.0380
   EscolaridadeSUPERIOR_COMPLETO  0.0705 0.0080   8.8375 0.0000  0.0549  0.0861
 EscolaridadeSUPERIOR_INCOMPLETO  0.0497 0.0072   6.9096 0.0000  0.0356  0.0638
                      RacaBRANCA -0.0361 0.0348  -1.0379 0.2993 -0.1042  0.0320
                    RacaINDÍGENA -0.1454 0.0636  -2.2863 0.0222 -0.2701 -0.0208
                 RacaPreta_Parda -0.0537 0.0348  -1.5428 0.1229 -0.1219  0.0145
                    votos.cidade  0.0000 0.0000   7.9796 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

As you can see, the `p-value` of the AME for the treatment variable is really high.

How can I interpret this to analyse the treatment effect? In what units is the AME of each variable? Is it percentage points?

Shouldn't the regression's coefficients significance mean anything?

Comment: I am sorry for the not great english

Comment: You don't appear to have a main effect of `Concorrencia`. Are you *sure* that's what you want? It is a very strange model & probably causing some distortion.

Comment: It could be a good idea to have that main effect. I guess I will make this adjustment and edit the question with the results in case that is needed

Comment: @gung just changed that... but I guess the original model had results that made more sense according to the theory. Anyway, I think the point of this thread is still the same

Comment: I don't know anything about your theory, but the signs flipped, & `Concorrencia` is wildly significant. What code did you run to get the average marginal effects?

Comment: I would expect theoretically that `Concorrencia` should be indeed negative and that the marginal effect of the treatment variable would become more negative with greate values of`Concorrencia`

Comment: @gung I ran just summary(margins(modelo))

Comment: What package is that in? There isn't a `margins()` function in the base packages.

Comment: @gung in a package also called `margins`

Comment: You need to include that information in the question.